# case when condition to handle dates in weekdays in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, date, view

I have oracle `View` where i want to create column `SYSTEM_INSERTED_DATE` which does not exist in table `TUA_PTI`.

In this `SYSTEM_INSERTED_DATE` column the value should be set for example if the current day is from Tuesday till Friday then the previous date should be shown and if the day is Monday then the date from Friday should be shown. Is it possible ?

Below is the DDL from the `view`:

```
Create View TES_RUS
(
        CLASS,
        TE_RPI
)
AS
Select 
 CLASS,
 TE_RPI
FROM TUA_PTI
```

Comment: View is just a SQL, it will not be able to capture when the data was inserted/updated in TUA_PTI, you may have to write a trigger and capture that information in a different table if you are not able to modify the table TUA_PTI.

Comment: 1. What you asked about can be done relatively easily with Oracle SQL date functions. 2. However, the date will depend on when you run the query. That doesn't really look like a true **inserted date**. The "inserted date" should be a fixed date, stored in the table, not a calculation - depending on the date when the query is run - in a view. 3. How do you handle the input date (whether `sysdate` or anything else) if it's a Saturday or Sunday? How do you handle "today is Friday, yesterday was a Thursday but it was a holiday, so the `inserted_date` must be the preceding Wednesday"?

Comment: for example now i have added new column "SYSTEM_INSERTED_DATE" and in the select clause mention as SYSDATE-1 then its giving correctly the date from yesterday bydefault now...but dont we use oracle date function here to recognize the current date and from this we can say for example if its Monday then the date from last Friday should be shown ?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your input is a date (**any** date), and you must compute "the previous workday" from that input, where "workweek" is defined as Monday through Friday. There are additional assumptions and requirements: the input date is a workday, and it may have time-of-day different from midnight; the output date must have time-of-day of midnight, and we don't need to consider "holidays" (off days that fall on a workday, such as Independence Day).

You can do something like this:

```
select trunc(input_date) - case when to_char(input_date, 'Dy') = 'Mon'
                           then 3 else 1 end
from   ...
```

This assumes your session's date language is English (or American or similar); if it is not, or if it may not be in the future or for another user, you can use the third argument to `to_char`:

```
to_char(input_date, 'Dy', 'nls_date_language=English')
```

Comment: for example now i have added new column  "SYSTEM_INSERTED_DATE"  and in the select clause mention as SYSDATE-1 then its giving correctly the date from yesterday bydefault now...but dont we use oracle date function here to recognize the current date and from this we can say for example if its Monday then the date  from last Friday should be shown ?